# Meteor: why are template events available to 'sub-templates', but template helpers not?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

If I have the following page structure:

```
<users template>
  <user template/>
  <user template/>
</user template>
```

Why is it that I can access `Template.users.events({})` from within the `<user template/>`, but not `Template.users.helpers({})`?

I wish I could access helpers from 'holder' templates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Template.registerHelper](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_registerhelper), this provides a way to create helpers that can be used across all templates.

[image: Template.registerHelper]

Parent events are triggered due to how events [bubble up](http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing) in javascript.

Comment: Thanks. However I don't want to make helpers available to ALL templates. Just 'child' templates

Comment: The problem is I think you are wishing that the templates had a OO inheritance, parent-child type of relationship, where templates (classes) could inherit methods from a super template (class).  This does not exist, even if, as I pointed out, it might kind of look like this is what happens with the event handling.  This is simply elements being nested in a tree structure (The DOM) that is allowing events to bubble up to from Template Instances to other Templates Instances higher in the DOM that they are embedded in.